# Polynomials and Algebras

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

For a Polynomial g over a Field K with $g=\sum_{i}^{}a_i X^i$,
when $v \in K$ is a zero of the associated polynomial function, e.g. $g(v) = 0$, one can split g as $g = (X-v)*h$ ($h \in K[X]$).

Is there something equivalent when plugging in elements of an Algebra over the field K, such as from the Space of Endomorphisms?
E.g. let V be a vectorspace and $\phi \in End(V)$ does $g(\phi) = 0$, where $0$ is the zero-mapping then give rise to something in the form $g = (X-?)*h$.

Specifically, for the polynomial $g = X^n$ when plugging in values of K one can split the zero $g(0) = 0$ with the linear factor $(X-0)$ n-times and implying $x=0$. What can be deduced from $g(\phi) = \phi \circ \phi \circ \phi ..... \circ \phi= 0_{mapp}$for lower powers $X^k,  k<n$

Comment: I would say such a splitting would look like: $g(\varphi(X)) = (\varphi(X)-\nu(X))*h(\varphi(X))$. But then it would have to vary over all $\varphi$, which only works if $|End(V)|=1$.

Comment: You can conclude that $g$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial of $\phi$. In fact, this is equivalent to $g(\phi) = 0$, so this is pretty much all you can conclude.